# How to configure multiple react projects using nginx?

Tags: nginx, react-router-dom

I have 3 different React projects, pointing to the same IP address with different ports.

Routing works accurately for the first project(default project)

For the other 2, routing works fine if I'm navigating from the very first page of the website.
For an instance, if I'm at `some.ip:3000` then I click something and now, I'm at `some.ip:3000/page`, it works fine
but if I try `some.ip:3000/page` directly, 404 page is returned.

Following is the **nginx configuration** - `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default`

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    server_name <private-IP>;

    root /var/www/<project1>;
    index index.html index.htm; 

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
    }
}

server {
    listen 3000;
    listen [::]:3000;
    server_name <private-IP>;

    root /var/www/<project2>;
    index index.html index.htm;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
}

server {
    listen 8000;
    listen [::]:8000;
    server_name <private-IP>;

    root /var/www/<project3>;
    index index.html index.htm;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
    }
}
```

Comment: Didn't you see the difference in your `try_files` directives for the first/third and the second project? BTW just `try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;` will be enough.

Comment: @IvanShatsky thanks for pointing it out, I was working on the third one, so overlooked the difference.
But I don't see any difference between the first one and the third one

Comment: Hmm, the third one doesn't work either? I don't see any errors for the third project. Is it index file called `index.html`, not the `index.htm`?

Comment: no, the index file is `index.html` only, `index.htm` is there just to be safe I guess 

Comment: yes, the 3rd, and the 2nd one are having issue

Comment: What happens if you try `try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;` instead?

Comment: It worked, thanks @IvanShatsky, appreciate your help :+1:
its now not pointing to 404, and is totally up to my React app